# Parallelisation of the Nested Loop

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp

My code is composed of two files. The main file, which has the loop over variable 'i' from 1 to 'kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)' and I used MPI to parallelise this loop. The main code is written below and the parallelisation for the loop is labelled on the 184th line.

```
PROGRAM TB_HAMILTONIAN
USE MPI
USE HAML
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER :: i, j, k
INTEGER :: num_wan
INTEGER :: num_nrpt
INTEGER :: ios(2)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: ndegen(:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: hr(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: rea_cons(3,3)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: rec_cons(3,3)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: tra(3)
CHARACTER (LEN=100) :: stri
INTEGER :: kb(3)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: eta
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_tb(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_kp(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evc(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evl(:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: kp(3)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: dk(3)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fe
REAL (KIND=dp) :: er(2)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: pi
REAL (KIND=dp) :: sa
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fq(3)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: tp
REAL (KIND=dp) :: hb
REAL (KIND=dp) :: el
REAL (KIND=dp) :: th
REAL (KIND=dp) :: cf
INTEGER :: nf
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: bcp1(:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: bcp2(:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: bcp3(:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp) :: br(9)
INTEGER :: cr, ti(2)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: ra
INTEGER :: world_size, world_rank, ierr
CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_rank,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count_rate=cr)
   ra = REAL(cr)
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(ti(1))
END IF
pi = DACOS(-1.0d0)
hb = 6.582119569d-16
el = 1.602176634d-19
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='wannier90.wout', STATUS='OLD', IOSTAT=ios(1))
   OPEN (UNIT=4, FILE='wannier90_hr.dat', STATUS='OLD', IOSTAT=ios(2))
   DO WHILE (ios(1) .EQ. 0)
      READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
      IF (TRIM(ADJUSTL(stri)) .EQ. 'Lattice Vectors (Ang)') THEN
          DO i = 1, 3, 1
             READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
             stri = ADJUSTL(stri)
             READ (UNIT=stri(4:), FMT=*) rea_cons(i,:)
          END DO
          EXIT
      END IF
   END DO
   DO WHILE (ios(1) .EQ. 0)
      READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
      IF (TRIM(ADJUSTL(stri)) .EQ. 'Reciprocal-Space Vectors (Ang^-1)') THEN
         DO i = 1, 3, 1
            READ (UNIT=3, FMT='(a)', IOSTAT=ios(1)) stri
            stri = ADJUSTL(stri)
            READ (UNIT=stri(4:), FMT=*) rec_cons(i,:)
         END DO
         EXIT
      END IF
   END DO
   CLOSE (UNIT=3)
   READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2))
   READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) num_wan
   READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) num_nrpt
END IF
CALL MPI_BCAST(num_wan,1,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(num_nrpt,1,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
ALLOCATE (ndegen(num_nrpt))
ALLOCATE (hr(num_wan**2*num_nrpt,7))
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   IF (MOD(num_nrpt, 15) .EQ. 0) THEN
      DO i = 1, num_nrpt / 15, 1
         READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) ndegen(1+(i-1)*15:15+(i-1)*15)
      END DO
   ELSE
      DO i = 1, num_nrpt / 15, 1
         READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) ndegen(1+(i-1)*15:15+(i-1)*15)
      END DO
      READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) ndegen(1+(num_nrpt/15)*15:num_nrpt)
   END IF
   DO i = 1, num_wan**2*num_nrpt, 1
      READ (UNIT=4, FMT=*, IOSTAT=ios(2)) hr(i,:)
   END DO
   CLOSE (UNIT=4)
   DO i = 1, num_wan**2*num_nrpt, 1
      tra(1) = hr(i,1) * rea_cons(1,1) + hr(i,2) * rea_cons(2,1) + hr(i,3) * rea_cons(3,1)
      tra(2) = hr(i,1) * rea_cons(1,2) + hr(i,2) * rea_cons(2,2) + hr(i,3) * rea_cons(3,2)
      tra(3) = hr(i,1) * rea_cons(1,3) + hr(i,2) * rea_cons(2,3) + hr(i,3) * rea_cons(3,3)
      hr(i,1:3) = tra
   END DO
END IF
CALL MPI_BCAST(ndegen,num_nrpt,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(hr,num_wan**2*num_nrpt*7,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN (UNIT=7, FILE='INPUT.dat', STATUS='OLD')
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) kb
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) eta
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) fe
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) er
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) sa
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) fq
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) tp
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*)
   READ (UNIT=7, FMT=*) th
   CLOSE (UNIT=7)
END IF
CALL MPI_BCAST(kb,3,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(eta,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(fe,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(er,2,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(sa,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(fq,3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(tp,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
nf = INT((fq(2)-fq(1))/fq(3)) + 1
ALLOCATE (ba_tb(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (ba_evc(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (ba_evl(num_wan))
ALLOCATE (ba_kp(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),3))
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   DO i = 1, kb(1), 1
      DO j = 1, kb(2), 1
         DO k = 1, kb(3), 1
            ba_kp((i-1)*kb(2)*kb(3)+(j-1)*kb(3)+k,1) = 0.0d0 + DBLE(i-1) * (1.0d0-0.0d0) / DBLE(kb(1))
            ba_kp((i-1)*kb(2)*kb(3)+(j-1)*kb(3)+k,2) = 0.0d0 + DBLE(j-1) * (1.0d0-0.0d0) / DBLE(kb(2))
            ba_kp((i-1)*kb(2)*kb(3)+(j-1)*kb(3)+k,3) = 0.0d0 + DBLE(k-1) * (1.0d0-0.0d0) / DBLE(kb(3))
         END DO
       END DO
   END DO
   DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1
      tra(1) = ba_kp(i,1) * rec_cons(1,1) + ba_kp(i,2) * rec_cons(2,1) + ba_kp(i,3) * rec_cons(3,1)
      tra(2) = ba_kp(i,1) * rec_cons(1,2) + ba_kp(i,2) * rec_cons(2,2) + ba_kp(i,3) * rec_cons(3,2)
      tra(3) = ba_kp(i,1) * rec_cons(1,3) + ba_kp(i,2) * rec_cons(2,3) + ba_kp(i,3) * rec_cons(3,3)
      ba_kp(i,:) = tra
   END DO
   IF (kb(1) /= 1) THEN
      dk(1) = DSQRT(rec_cons(1,1)**2+rec_cons(1,2)**2+rec_cons(1,3)**2) / DBLE(kb(1)) / 2.0d0 / pi
   ELSE
      dk(1) = 1.0d0
   END IF
   IF (kb(2) /= 1) THEN
      dk(2) = DSQRT(rec_cons(2,1)**2+rec_cons(2,2)**2+rec_cons(2,3)**2) / DBLE(kb(2)) / 2.0d0 / pi
   ELSE
      dk(2) = 1.0d0
   END IF
   IF (kb(3) /= 1) THEN
      dk(3) = DSQRT(rec_cons(3,1)**2+rec_cons(3,2)**2+rec_cons(3,3)**2) / DBLE(kb(3)) / 2.0d0 / pi
   ELSE
      dk(3) = 1.0d0
   END IF
END IF
CALL MPI_BCAST(ba_kp,kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
ALLOCATE (bcp1(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),nf,9))
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   ALLOCATE (bcp2(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),nf,9))
   bcp2 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   ALLOCATE (bcp3(kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3),nf,9))
   bcp3 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
END IF
ba_tb = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1 !!!This is the 184th line
   IF (MOD(i-1,world_size) /= world_rank) CYCLE
   kp = ba_kp(i,:)
   CALL CIRCULARPHOTOGALVANICEFFECT(i,ndegen,num_wan,num_nrpt,kp,hr,ba_tb,ba_evc,ba_evl,fe,er,pi,sa,fq,nf,tp,hb,bcp1)
   IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
!!!???      bcp2 = bcp2 + bcp1
      DO j = 1, world_size-1, 1
         IF (i-1+j == kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)) EXIT
         k = i + j + 1000
         CALL MPI_RECV(bcp3,kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)*6,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,j,k,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
         bcp2 = bcp2 + bcp3
      END DO
   ELSE
      k = i + 1000
      CALL MPI_SEND(bcp1,kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3)*6,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,k,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
   END IF
END DO
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   cf = pi * el * el * el / hb / hb / (rea_cons(1,1)*rea_cons(1,2)*th)
   br = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1
      DO j = 1, nf, 1
         br = br + bcp2(i,j,:)
      END DO
   END DO
   OPEN (UNIT=8, FILE='circularphotogalvaniceffect.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT='(A34)') 'xx, xy, xz, yx, yy, yz, zx, zy, zz'
   DO i = 1, nf, 1
      WRITE(UNIT=8, FMT=*) fq(1) + fq(3) * (i-1)
      WRITE(UNIT=8, FMT=*) br * dk(1) * dk(2) * dk(3)
   END DO
   WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*)
   DO i = 1, kb(1)*kb(2)*kb(3), 1
      WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT='(3(F12.8,3X))') ba_kp(i,:)
      WRITE (UNIT=8, FMT=*) bcp2(i,:,:) * dk(1) * dk(2) * dk(3)
   END DO
END IF
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(ti(2))
   WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT='(A,F15.8)') 'Time for all (seconds):', (ti(2) - ti(1)) / ra
END IF
DEALLOCATE (ba_tb)
DEALLOCATE (ba_kp)
DEALLOCATE (ba_evc)
DEALLOCATE (ba_evl)
DEALLOCATE (bcp1)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   DEALLOCATE (bcp2)
   DEALLOCATE (bcp3)
   CLOSE (UNIT=8)
END IF
CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
DEALLOCATE (ndegen)
DEALLOCATE (hr)
STOP
END PROGRAM
```

Inside this loop, the subroutine is called and this subroutine is stored in another file, which is written below.

```
MODULE HAML
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE CIRCULARPHOTOGALVANICEFFECT(ix,ndegen,num_wan,num_nrpt,kp,hr,ba_tb,ba_evc,ba_evl,fe,er,pi,sa,fq,nf,tp,hb,bcp1)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER :: i, j, k, l
INTEGER :: ix
INTEGER :: num_wan
INTEGER :: num_nrpt
REAL (KIND=dp) :: kp(3)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: ndegen(:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: hr(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_tb(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fe
REAL (KIND=dp) :: er(2)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fd(2)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: kb
REAL (KIND=dp) :: hb
COMPLEX (KIND=dp) :: bcp1(:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: pbc(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra1(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra2(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra31(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra32(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra41(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra42(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra51(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra52(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra53(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra54(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra55(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra56(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra57(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra58(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra59(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra60(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra61(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra62(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp) :: dc(3)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evc(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evl(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: vx(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: vy(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: vz(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: w(:)
INTEGER :: n, lda, lwork, info
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: rwork(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: work(:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: sa
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fq(3)
INTEGER :: nf
REAL (KIND=dp) :: tp
REAL (KIND=dp) :: pi
REAL (KIND=dp) :: lg
ba_tb = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
dc(1) = (0.0d0, 1.0d0)
kb = 8.617333262d-5
ALLOCATE (tra1(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra2(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (vx(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (vy(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (vz(num_wan,num_wan))
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      ba_tb(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + ba_tb(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
vx = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      dc(3) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1), 0.0d0)
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2) * dc(1) * dc(3)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      vx(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + vx(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
vy = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      dc(3) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2), 0.0d0)
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2) * dc(1) * dc(3)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      vy(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + vy(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
vz = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      dc(3) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3), 0.0d0)
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2) * dc(1) * dc(3)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      vz(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + vz(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
ba_evc = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
ba_evl = 0.0d0
n = num_wan
lda = num_wan
ALLOCATE (a(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (w(num_wan))
ALLOCATE(work(2*num_wan-1))
lwork = 2 * num_wan - 1
ALLOCATE(rwork(3*num_wan-2))
a = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
w = 0.0d0
work = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
rwork = 0.0d0
a = ba_tb
CALL ZHEEV('V','L',n,a,lda,w,work,lwork,rwork,info)
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   ba_evc(i,:) = a(i,:)
END DO
ba_evl = w
ALLOCATE (tra31(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra32(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra41(num_wan,1))
ALLOCATE (tra42(num_wan,1))
ALLOCATE (tra51(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra52(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra53(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra54(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra55(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra56(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra57(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra58(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra59(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra60(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra61(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra62(1,1))
ALLOCATE (pbc(9))
bcp1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, nf, 1 !!!This is the 183rd line
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      IF ((ba_evl(j) >= er(1)) .AND. (ba_evl(j) <= er(2))) THEN
         tra31(1,:) = DCONJG(ba_evc(:,j))
         tra41(:,1) = ba_evc(:,j)
         fd(1) = 1.0d0 / (EXP((ba_evl(j)-fe)/kb/tp) + 1.0d0)
         DO k = j+1, num_wan, 1
            IF ((ba_evl(k) >= er(1)) .AND. (ba_evl(k) <= er(2))) THEN
               tra32(1,:) = DCONJG(ba_evc(:,k))
               tra42(:,1) = ba_evc(:,k)
               fd(2) = 1.0d0 / (EXP((ba_evl(k)-fe)/kb/tp) + 1.0d0)
               lg = 1.0d0 / sa / DSQRT(2.0d0*pi) * EXP((-5.0d-1)*((hb*(fq(1)+fq(3)*DBLE(i-1))-(ba_evl(j)-ba_evl(k))-fe)/sa)**2)
               tra51 = MATMUL(tra31,vx)
               tra52 = MATMUL(tra32,vx)
               tra53 = MATMUL(tra31,vy)
               tra54 = MATMUL(tra32,vy)
               tra55 = MATMUL(tra31,vz)
               tra56 = MATMUL(tra32,vz)
               tra57 = MATMUL(tra51,tra42)
               tra58 = MATMUL(tra52,tra41)
               tra59 = MATMUL(tra53,tra42)
               tra60 = MATMUL(tra56,tra41)
               tra61 = MATMUL(tra55,tra42)
               tra62 = MATMUL(tra54,tra41)
               pbc(1) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg
               pbc(2) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(3) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(4) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra59-tra62) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg
               pbc(5) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra59-tra62) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(6) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra59-tra62) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(7) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra61-tra60) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg
               pbc(8) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra61-tra60) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(9) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra61-tra60) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
            END IF
            bcp1(ix,i,1) = bcp1(ix,i,1) + pbc(1)
            bcp1(ix,i,2) = bcp1(ix,i,2) + pbc(2)
            bcp1(ix,i,3) = bcp1(ix,i,3) + pbc(3)
            bcp1(ix,i,4) = bcp1(ix,i,4) + pbc(4)
            bcp1(ix,i,5) = bcp1(ix,i,5) + pbc(5)
            bcp1(ix,i,6) = bcp1(ix,i,6) + pbc(6)
            bcp1(ix,i,7) = bcp1(ix,i,7) + pbc(7)
            bcp1(ix,i,8) = bcp1(ix,i,8) + pbc(8)
            bcp1(ix,i,9) = bcp1(ix,i,9) + pbc(9)
         END DO
      END IF
   END DO
END DO
DEALLOCATE (tra1)
DEALLOCATE (tra2)
DEALLOCATE (tra31)
DEALLOCATE (tra32)
DEALLOCATE (tra41)
DEALLOCATE (tra42)
DEALLOCATE (tra51)
DEALLOCATE (tra52)
DEALLOCATE (tra53)
DEALLOCATE (tra54)
DEALLOCATE (tra55)
DEALLOCATE (tra56)
DEALLOCATE (tra57)
DEALLOCATE (tra58)
DEALLOCATE (tra59)
DEALLOCATE (tra60)
DEALLOCATE (tra61)
DEALLOCATE (tra62)
DEALLOCATE (a)
DEALLOCATE (w)
DEALLOCATE (work)
DEALLOCATE (rwork)
DEALLOCATE (vx)
DEALLOCATE (vy)
DEALLOCATE (vz)
DEALLOCATE (pbc)
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE CIRCULARPHOTOGALVANICEFFECT
END MODULE HAML
```

Within this subroutine file, another loop, which is labelled on the 183rd line, runs the variable 'i' from 1 to 'nf'. The whole calculation takes about 4.5 hours.

I want to further speed up calculation so I parallelise this loop (the 183rd line) as well. The new subroutine code is written below.

```
MODULE HAML
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE CIRCULARPHOTOGALVANICEFFECT(ix,ndegen,num_wan,num_nrpt,kp,hr,ba_tb,ba_evc,ba_evl,fe,er,pi,sa,fq,nf,tp,hb,bcp1)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER :: i, j, k, l
INTEGER :: ix
INTEGER :: num_wan
INTEGER :: num_nrpt
REAL (KIND=dp) :: kp(3)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: ndegen(:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: hr(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_tb(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fe
REAL (KIND=dp) :: er(2)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fd(2)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: kb
REAL (KIND=dp) :: hb
COMPLEX (KIND=dp) :: bcp1(:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: pbc(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: cu(:,:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra1(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra2(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra31(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra32(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra41(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra42(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra51(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra52(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra53(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra54(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra55(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra56(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra57(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra58(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra59(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra60(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra61(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra62(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp) :: dc(3)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evc(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: ba_evl(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: vx(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: vy(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: vz(:,:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:)
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: w(:)
INTEGER :: n, lda, lwork, info
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: rwork(:)
COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: work(:)
REAL (KIND=dp) :: sa
REAL (KIND=dp) :: fq(3)
INTEGER :: nf
REAL (KIND=dp) :: tp
REAL (KIND=dp) :: pi
REAL (KIND=dp) :: lg
INTEGER :: omp_get_num_threads
INTEGER :: omp_get_thread_num
INTEGER :: num_thread
INTEGER :: id_thread
ba_tb = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
dc(1) = (0.0d0, 1.0d0)
kb = 8.617333262d-5
ALLOCATE (tra1(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra2(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (vx(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (vy(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (vz(num_wan,num_wan))
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      ba_tb(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + ba_tb(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
vx = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      dc(3) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1), 0.0d0)
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2) * dc(1) * dc(3)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      vx(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + vx(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
vy = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      dc(3) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2), 0.0d0)
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2) * dc(1) * dc(3)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      vy(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + vy(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
tra1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
vz = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_nrpt, 1
   tra2 = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
   DO j = 1, num_wan**2, 1
      k = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,4)
      l = hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,5)
      dc(2) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,6), hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,7))
      dc(3) = CMPLX(hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3), 0.0d0)
      tra2(k,l) = EXP(dc(1)*((kp(1)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,1))&
                +(kp(2)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,2))&
                +(kp(3)*hr(j+(i-1)*num_wan**2,3)))) * dc(2) * dc(1) * dc(3)
   END DO
   tra2 = tra2 / DBLE(ndegen(i))
   tra1 = tra1 + tra2
END DO
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      vz(i,j) = tra1(i,j) + vz(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
ba_evc = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
ba_evl = 0.0d0
n = num_wan
lda = num_wan
ALLOCATE (a(num_wan,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (w(num_wan))
ALLOCATE(work(2*num_wan-1))
lwork = 2 * num_wan - 1
ALLOCATE(rwork(3*num_wan-2))
a = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
w = 0.0d0
work = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
rwork = 0.0d0
a = ba_tb
CALL ZHEEV('V','L',n,a,lda,w,work,lwork,rwork,info)
DO i = 1, num_wan, 1
   ba_evc(i,:) = a(i,:)
END DO
ba_evl = w
ALLOCATE (tra31(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra32(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra41(num_wan,1))
ALLOCATE (tra42(num_wan,1))
ALLOCATE (tra51(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra52(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra53(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra54(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra55(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra56(1,num_wan))
ALLOCATE (tra57(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra58(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra59(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra60(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra61(1,1))
ALLOCATE (tra62(1,1))
!$OMP PARALLEL default(none) shared(num_thread)
num_thread = omp_get_num_threads()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
ALLOCATE (cu(num_thread,nf,9))
cu = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
ALLOCATE (pbc(9))
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i,j,tra31,tra41,fd,k,tra32,tra42,lg,tra51,tra52,tra53,tra54,tra55,tra56,tra57,tra58,&
                          tra59,tra60,tra61,tra62,pbc) &
!$OMP             SHARED(nf,num_wan,ba_evl,er,ba_evc,fe,kb,tp,sa,pi,hb,fq,vx,vy,vz,dc,cu)
DO i = 1, nf, 1
   DO j = 1, num_wan, 1
      IF ((ba_evl(j) >= er(1)) .AND. (ba_evl(j) <= er(2))) THEN
         tra31(1,:) = DCONJG(ba_evc(:,j))
         tra41(:,1) = ba_evc(:,j)
         fd(1) = 1.0d0 / (EXP((ba_evl(j)-fe)/kb/tp) + 1.0d0)
         DO k = j+1, num_wan, 1
            IF ((ba_evl(k) >= er(1)) .AND. (ba_evl(k) <= er(2))) THEN
               tra32(1,:) = DCONJG(ba_evc(:,k))
               tra42(:,1) = ba_evc(:,k)
               fd(2) = 1.0d0 / (EXP((ba_evl(k)-fe)/kb/tp) + 1.0d0)
               lg = 1.0d0 / sa / DSQRT(2.0d0*pi) * EXP((-5.0d-1)*((hb*(fq(1)+fq(3)*DBLE(i-1))-(ba_evl(j)-ba_evl(k))-fe)/sa)**2)
               tra51 = MATMUL(tra31,vx)
               tra52 = MATMUL(tra32,vx)
               tra53 = MATMUL(tra31,vy)
               tra54 = MATMUL(tra32,vy)
               tra55 = MATMUL(tra31,vz)
               tra56 = MATMUL(tra32,vz)
               tra57 = MATMUL(tra51,tra42)
               tra58 = MATMUL(tra52,tra41)
               tra59 = MATMUL(tra53,tra42)
               tra60 = MATMUL(tra56,tra41)
               tra61 = MATMUL(tra55,tra42)
               tra62 = MATMUL(tra54,tra41)
               pbc(1) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg
               pbc(2) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(3) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(4) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra59-tra62) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg
               pbc(5) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra59-tra62) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(6) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra59-tra62) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(7) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra61-tra60) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg
               pbc(8) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra61-tra60) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
               pbc(9) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra61-tra60) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra57))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))&
                        +(dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra58))) * lg
            END IF
            id_thread = omp_get_thread_num() + 1
            cu(id_thread,i,1) = cu(id_thread,i,1) + pbc(1)
            cu(id_thread,i,2) = cu(id_thread,i,2) + pbc(2)
            cu(id_thread,i,3) = cu(id_thread,i,3) + pbc(3)
            cu(id_thread,i,4) = cu(id_thread,i,4) + pbc(4)
            cu(id_thread,i,5) = cu(id_thread,i,5) + pbc(5)
            cu(id_thread,i,6) = cu(id_thread,i,6) + pbc(6)
            cu(id_thread,i,7) = cu(id_thread,i,7) + pbc(7)
            cu(id_thread,i,8) = cu(id_thread,i,8) + pbc(8)
            cu(id_thread,i,9) = cu(id_thread,i,9) + pbc(9)
         END DO
      END IF
   END DO
END DO
!!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
bcp1 = DCMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
DO i = 1, num_thread, 1
   DO j = 1, nf, 1
      bcp1(ix,j,:) = bcp1(ix,j,:) + cu(i,j,:)
   END DO
END DO
DEALLOCATE (tra1)
DEALLOCATE (tra2)
DEALLOCATE (tra31)
DEALLOCATE (tra32)
DEALLOCATE (tra41)
DEALLOCATE (tra42)
DEALLOCATE (tra51)
DEALLOCATE (tra52)
DEALLOCATE (tra53)
DEALLOCATE (tra54)
DEALLOCATE (tra55)
DEALLOCATE (tra56)
DEALLOCATE (tra57)
DEALLOCATE (tra58)
DEALLOCATE (tra59)
DEALLOCATE (tra60)
DEALLOCATE (tra61)
DEALLOCATE (tra62)
DEALLOCATE (a)
DEALLOCATE (w)
DEALLOCATE (work)
DEALLOCATE (rwork)
DEALLOCATE (vx)
DEALLOCATE (vy)
DEALLOCATE (vz)
DEALLOCATE (pbc)
DEALLOCATE (cu)
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE CIRCULARPHOTOGALVANICEFFECT
END MODULE HAML
```

However, the whole calculation takes 4.9 hours. Would anyone please give me some suggestions on the parallelisation for the nested loop; particularly, the inner loop or how to imporve my code to further speed up the calculation?

Many thanks in advances.

Comment: First, before you even begin to think about parallelism, I strongly suggest that you simplify the code in the loop - for instance `MATMUL(MATMUL(tra31,vx),tra42))` is used more than once. The compiler is extremely unlikely to recognise this and so you will end up doing many more matrix multiplies than you need. Depending on the size of your matrices this may give you much more speed up than any easy form of parallelism will give you

Comment: Which one is line 159? Put a comment in the code.

Comment: Your use of `matmul` will be very hard to make parallel with MPI. OpenMP should be doable.

Comment: @Ian Bush Thank you for the suggestion. Do you mean that I should write another subroutine that runs MATMUL function for two matrix?

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout Thank you for the suggestion. I know it is not easy to see the 159th line but I put '!!!This is the 159th line' as a comment behind the loop. 'DO i = 1, nf, 1 !!!This is the 159th line' Would you please take a look at it again?

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout Previously, I used OpenMP to parallelise the loop on the 159th line but I found that the hybrid the parallelization does not speed up the code a lot. Is it possible parallelise this loop with MPI as well? Would you please recommend some examples doing the parallelisation with MPI for the nested loop? Thank you.

Comment: MPI is not as easy as you seem to think it is. Have you written any MPI programs? If so, start converting this code of yours, and then ask something specific.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout I use the MPI to parallelise the outer loop on the 184th line in the main code but I do not know how to parallelise the nested loop. Would you please give me some examples or any example to parallelise the nested loop (both outer and inner loop)? Thank you.

Comment: @Kieran I repeat before you even think of parallelisation simplify the complete mess that is in the loop. Work out the subexpressions so Matmuls are only evaluated once and store them in temporaries. Implement that. Check it works. Marvel at how much faster it is than what you have currently. And then, and only then, think about parallelisation.

Comment: @Ian Bush I modified my subroutine code, which only computes the MATMUL function once and the whole calculation becomes faster than before. It takes about 4.5 hours. I want to further speed up my code so I parallelise this inner loop with OpenMP; however, the new code takes about 4.9 hours. I update my psoter. Would you please have a look at it and give me some more suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout I parallelise the subroutine code with OpenMP and update my poster. However, the new code takes about 4.9 hours. Would you please have a look at it and give me some more suggestions on how to further improve my parallelisation? Thank you.

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) Have you profiled your code to see what's taking all the time? Always profile before optimising. 2) If you have arrays of size `(1,1)`, why are they not just scalars? Then you wouldn't need to `SUM` them. 3) Inside the `k` loop, if the `if` isn't satisfied, you're not setting `pbc`, but you are still adding `pbc` to `cu`. 4) Your code would be a lot easier to read if you used whole-array statements. Things like `vz = tra1 + vz` rather than `do i=1,num_wan; do j=1,num_wan; vz(i,j) = vz(i,j)+tra1(i,j); done; done`

Comment: Well first get your array indices the right way around  - Fortran is column major and many of your array accesses are done in about the slowest way possible. And your use of `Matmul` is *very* strange - I am currently sat on a beach and can't be bothered to work out exactly what you are doing, but are you sure this is the best way to calculate this? Would it be  possible to write out mathematically what you are trying to do in these loops?

Comment: @veryreverie Thank you for the suggestion. Regarding your 2nd point, do you mean just take matrix element; instead of using SUM function; for example, change 'pbc(1) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * SUM(tra57-tra58) * ((dc(1)*SUM(tra59))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra60))+(dc(1)*SUM(tra61))*(dc(1)*SUM(tra62))) * lg' to 'pbc(1) = (fd(1)-fd(2)) * (tra57(1,1)-tra58(1,1)) * ((dc(1)*tra59(1,1))*(dc(1)*tra60(1,1))+(dc(1)*tra61(1,1))*(dc(1)*tra62(1,1))) * lg'?

Comment: @Ian Bush Thank you for the suggestion. I will modify the array indices and compare the MATMUL with the direct mathematical computation.

Comment: I mean that for example you have `COMPLEX (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE :: tra57(:,:)`, `ALLOCATE (tra57(1,1))` and `SUM(tra57)`. It would be much simpler to just have `complex(dp) tra57` and then `tra57` rather than `sum(tra57)`. Now it's possible that the compiler is smart enough to optimise this away, but it's also very possible that it isn't.

Comment: Actually, speaking of; what compiler are you using, and what optimisation flags are you passing it?

Comment: First concentrate on the optimizations suggested by others (loop  ordering, compiler flags, not repeating the same,...). Then: How long did the code take without MPI? How long does it take with MPI on one process? Are the results correct? How long does it take with two proceses? Results still correct?

Comment: @veryreverie Can I ask one more question? In my main code, I used 'bcp2 = bcp2 + bcp1' to collect the data from the root processor. I labelled this line with '!!!???' sign at the beginning of this line.

Is it correct or should I use 'bcp2 = bcp1' to collect the data from the root processor?

Thank you.

Comment: A quick look at your code suggests it shouldn't matter as you've set `bcp2` to zero beforehand (although `bcp2 = bcp1` would certainly be the clearer of the two).

Comment: @veryreverie Thank you for the reply. Suppose the root processor executed the loop two times; then, there are 'bcp1' arrays generated by the root processor. To collect all data from these two 'bcp1' arrays, I suppose I should add them together; such as 'bcp2 = bcp2 + bcp1'. However, my colleague tell me that I should use 'bcp2 = bcp1'. I am confused about it. Would you please give me more suggestions? Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, yep, my quick look was too quick. `bcp2=bcp1` will make the two equal at the start of every iteration. `bcp2=bcp2+bcp1` will make the two equal at the start of the first iteration, but then in future iterations will add `bcp1` to whatever was there at the end of the last iteration. So which is appropriate will depend on what you are trying to do.